# I have some questions about the return value of the make_circles function in python

Tags: python-3.x

`X,y = make_circles(n_samples=50, shuffle=True, noise=None, random_state=0, factor=0.8)`

I already know that there are two return values. But why `X[y == 0,0]` is right? How is it indexed?

Each line in X has only two parameters. Why can you use y to determine whether each sample is a class of 0 or 1?

Comment: Are you referring to [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_circles.html)? Python has no built-in `make_circles` function.

Comment: Yeah, I used sklearn.datasets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sklearn's [make_circles](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_circles.html) returns a tuple X, y. `X` is a 2d array where each row represents the x and y coordinate of a point. `y` is an array representing whether the corresponding point (point on the same row/index) is a part of the inner (class 1) or outer circle (class 0). `X[y==0,0]` says give me all the points in `X` that are of class 0 (in the outer circle) and then give me their x coordinate.